# Selenium IDE 3.x - Verify content of a variable

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, ide

Good Morning, 
I am struggling with a variable in Selenium IDE 3 and was hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction.
Basically, I've created a variable and stored the value's of a dropdown.  This seems to have worked correctly for when I use the echo command, I can see the value of the variable.

echo: Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas California Colorado Connecticut Delaware District of Columbia Florida Georgia Hawaii Idaho Illinois Indiana Iowa Kansas Kentucky Louisiana Maine Maryland Massachusetts Michigan Minnesota Mississippi Missouri Montana Nebraska Nevada New Hampshire New Jersey New Mexico North Carolina North Dakota Ohio Oklahoma Oregon Pennsylvania Rhode Island South Carolina South Dakota Tennessee Texas Utah Vermont Virginia Washington West Virginia Wisconsin Wyoming

I wrote the echo command as the following:
echo    ${IssueState}

Where I am stuck:  I would like to compare the contents of this variable to a list of states (Depending on the product chosen, the list of states available in the dropdown can change.

I've tried to 
verify text    ${IssueState}=='my list of states'
I've also tried assert with no luck.

Any ideas how I can accomplish what I am looking to do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code trials please?

Comment: {
      "id": "a0f1acd1-e4a6-4100-9463-7830d715c055",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "storeText",
      "target": "css=#Insured\\.State\\|0 .form-control",
      "targets": [
        ["css=#Insured\\.State\\|0 .form-control", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='Insured.State|0']/div[2]/select", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//div[2]/select", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": "IssueState"
    }

Comment: {
      "id": "80cfb543-2c93-4247-878b-7e24a8575d9a",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "${IssueState}",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }

Comment: {
      "id": "a58617a1-679f-4c64-aa75-e0ab02ba531f",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "assertValue",
      "target": "${IssueState}",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas California Colorado Connecticut Delaware District of Columbia Florida Georgia Hawaii Idaho Illinois Indiana Iowa Kansas Kentucky Louisiana Maine Maryland Massachusetts Michigan Minnesota Mississippi Missouri Montana Nebraska Nevada New Hampshire New J..."